# Python BeautifulSoup is unnecessarily slow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

While this code works pretty fast:

```
for olay in soup("li", {"class":"textb"}):
    tanim = olay("strong")
    try:
        print tanim[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Getting string property like this makes this code considerably slower:

```
for olay in soup("li", {"class":"textb"}):
    tanim = olay("strong")
    try:
        print tanim[0].string
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

My question is, am I doing something that I shouldn't getting string property like that? Should I have used something else to get plain text version of an object?

Update:
This is also working pretty fast, so slowness is unique to string property I guess?

```
for olay in soup("li", {"class":"textb"}):
    tanim = olay("strong")
    try:
        print tanim[0].text
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, `.text` is slowest, with the other two being about the same. The overall difference is not much, though. So the question is: what are you testing, and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the string representation of `tanim[0]`. You should just do: `print str(tanim[0])`. Also, do a `dir(tanim[0])` to see if it has a property called `string` at all.

```
for olay in soup("li", {"class":"textb"}):
    tanim = olay("strong")
    try:
        print str(tanim[0])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

For everyone to provide a better answer, you could also post the target HTML or the URI and mention which bit you are trying to extract out of it.